# moment.local() not working in Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, momentjs

I need to display local time (converted from UTC) on Firefox browser. I read available posts and tried below things. Yet I am getting incorrect time.
Any help would be appreciated!

Time when record created : Feb 10, 2016 2.29 PM EST.
I Stored it in the server at UTC Time i.e 7:29 PM Wednesday UTC

Now to Display the local time to user In **Mozilla FireFox**

Tried :
1)

`new Date($scope.SavedDate).toLocaleDateString()` ==> Gives UTC time in Mozilla (It gives correct Time in Chrome)

2)Tried to use moment.js

```
var localDate = moment.utc(new Date($scope.SavedDate)).local();

$scope.SavedDate = localDate;
```

Actual Time coming from server:

[image]

Time after using moment.js: (Screenshot from developer console)

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: To be clear, what exactly is the value of `$scope.SavedDate`? Is it `2016-02-10T19:30:00`?

Comment: There's no timezone specified in `2016-02-10T19:30:00` so each browser is interpreting it differently (Chrome assumes local, FF assumes UTC). Append timezone at the end or convert to UTC and append a `z` like `2016-02-10T19:30:00z`

Comment: Part of the problem here is that ES2015 changed the rule about the default time zone for ISO dates without an explicit time zone. The old spec said that it should be interpreted as UTC, but the new spec says it should be local.

Comment: @Pointy—you might enjoy reading the [*TC39 discussion*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87). ECMAScript 2015 appeared to have gotten it right (sans time zone == local). However, for the sake of a squeaky wheel, any semblance of consistency was abandoned when it was decided to treat date–only forms without a timezone as UTC, but date **with** time as local (per ISO 8601). Go figure.

Comment: @AnthonyChu : Your comment was helpful. It works now!